# Swift 4 : Having different values to each CollectionView Items

Tags: swift, firebase

**Practice, practice, and practice..**

came up with an idea today. making a simple quiz app. and i had everything planned, so when it came to the `CollectionView` part, things got so complex.

So i have 1 section and 4 items in it. and a swift struct. 
here's my struct code

```
struct Questions {
    let QuestionTitle : String
    let QuestionAnswer0 : String
    let QuestionAnswer1 : String
    let QuestionAnswer2 : String
    let QuestionAnswer3 : String
    let CorrectAnswer : String // leave this one
}
```

However i have an example data inserted to this struct, from the QuestionAnswer0 to QuestionAnswer3 have it's string

and here's my `CollectionView` code

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
   return 1 // one section
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 4 // four answers
}
```

And the complex part is, questions are coming from firebase. my firebase structure looks something like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mjhj.png)

and the way i load them

```
func loadQuestions() {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    //let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    ref.child("Questions").observe( .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let questionTitle1 = snapshot.key

        let An0 = value?["0"] as? String ?? ""
        let An1 = value?["1"] as? String ?? ""
        let An2 = value?["2"] as? String ?? ""
        let An3 = value?["3"] as? String ?? ""
        let crct = value?["Correct"] as? String ?? ""

        self.QuestionsLoaded.insert(Questions(QuestionTitle : questionTitle1 ,QuestionAnswer0: An0 , QuestionAnswer1: An1 , QuestionAnswer2: An2 , QuestionAnswer3: An3, CorrectAnswer: crct) , at: 0)

        self.MyCollectionView.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }    
}
```

okay so the data is loaded now, let's sort them out. My CollectionView code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell0CollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            cell.qn.text = QuestionsLoaded[indexPath.row].QuestionAnswer0
        } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
            cell.qn.text = QuestionsLoaded[indexPath.row].QuestionAnswer1
        } else if indexPath.item == 2 {
            cell.qn.text = QuestionsLoaded[indexPath.row].QuestionAnswer2
        } else if indexPath.item == 3 {
            cell.qn.text = QuestionsLoaded[indexPath.row].QuestionAnswer3
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

finally, at the first moment of launch, it returns

> fatal error: Index out of range

Thank you so much for helping me

**EDIT** 
i know what causes this error, before my questions load, the collection view automatically returns four empty items, which causes the index out of range

here this comes on the log

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

and after a few minutes, it crashes but the questions load

is there anyway to delay this for a few seconds, or some right ways to handle this ?

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 4 // four answers
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what's the count of `QuestionsLoaded` array?

Comment: for this purpose, it comes from the struct, which is one question and four answers

Comment: Does it mean that it contains one `Questions` element?

Comment: Yeah. it has, here's the `var QuestionsLoaded = [Questions]()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you there is *only* one element in the `QuestionsLoaded` array, thus you are trying to access `QuestionsLoaded[indexPath.row]` which leads to "Index out of range" error. The problem is you are saying that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 4 // four answers
}
```

and you are trying to get the element based on the number of the item, to make it more clear, when trying to draw the second cell -for example-, the value of `indexPath.row` would be 1 which is *not* compatible with the array element index (`QuestionsLoaded` only contains 1 element, i.e: `QuestionsLoaded[0]` is the only valid one).

To solve this, you would need to implement it like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell0CollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            cell.qn.text = QuestionsLoaded[0].QuestionAnswer0
        } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
            cell.qn.text = QuestionsLoaded[0].QuestionAnswer1
        } else if indexPath.item == 2 {
            cell.qn.text = QuestionsLoaded[0].QuestionAnswer2
        } else if indexPath.item == 3 {
            cell.qn.text = QuestionsLoaded[0].QuestionAnswer3
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Update:**

In case of `QuestionsLoaded` is empty, `numberOfItemsInSection` data source method should returns 0:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return QuestionsLoaded.isEmpty ? 0 : 4
}
```

which leads to never reach `cellForItemAt` data source method unless there is an element in the `QuestionsLoaded` array. Obviously, after calling `self.MyCollectionView.reloadData()` the method will be get called again with non-empty data source and it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your time, unfortunately yours returns the same error, i don't know for the past 2 years i haven't faced a question like this, can't get my head around it

Comment: i think my code is wrong, i've deleted every code and tried to run it, also trying to print my struct, but it cant be done, it even returns that error for `print (QuestionsLoaded[indexPath.row].QuestionAnswer1)`

Comment: Where exactly the error occurs? I assume it should work fine. Make sure that your array does has an element. Also, you might want to `append` to the array instead of `insert`.

Comment: Thank  You so much for being with me until it's solved, it works super-fine now, you deserve the right check mark, again i appreciate your help

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar glad to help! aside bar hint, as naming convention when declaring instances, it should start with small letter, such as: `questionsLoaded` instead of `QuestionsLoaded` and `myCollectionView` instead of `MyCollectionView`. What you did should be applicable when naming a class or a struct for example.